# Browser freezes while watching Youtube

Tags: google-chrome, browser, youtube, microsoft-edge

my browser freezes when I watch youtube videos, I already tried changing browsers, but it doesn't work. I tried using Microsoft Edge, Opera, Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Google. All of them don't work and I need help because this thing is pissing me off so bad. I already tried reinstalling as well.

Comment: Have you done any speed tests?  Are you able to download video content and then watch it offline?  What exactly fo you mean by "Browser Freezes"? Are you using WIFI?  If so  does using a cable make the problem go away?  Do other devices suffer from this problem? Have you tried rebooting your router?

Comment: Could be your PC is too slow, your network is too slow, or other reasons. 1. Can you view the video in lower resolution? 2. Can you download it and view it at full resolution?